How can I select the highest level occuring descendant *only* in css?
Consider this example, a,b,c,d are just random tags. The d-tag marked with with class="select" are the ones I want to select. Of course, I dont have a class on them.
The rule should be: Select the highest-level occuring descendant only, so from outhermost to innermost - the first time the d-tag occures.
<container>
  <a>
    <b>
      <a>
        <c><d class="select"></d></c>
      </a>
    </b>
  </a>
  <a>
    <d class="select">
      <a>
        <c><d><a><d></d></a></d></c>
      </a>
    </d>
  </a>
</container>

Can this be done in CSS?

Please define "highest-level". Also, what have you tried?

"highest-level occuring descendant". I'm sorry, I dont know what you dont understand.

What does highest level mean to you? Appearing first in the HTML document? Closer to the root in terms of the DOM? Etc.

@j08691 as in the example, the with class="selected" marked elements, that are the highest level of their type as all other are descendants. As in descendare: going down, so having a lower level.

Basically no. you would need javascript

You could select the ds which are not descendants of another d - d:not(d d)
This snippet has replaced the a tag as that has other meaning and also has added a character into each element so we can see what is being changed.


x,
a,
b,
c,
d {
  color: black;
}

d:not(d d) {
  color: red;
}
<container>
  <x>x
    <b>b
      <x>x
        <c>c<d class="select">select</d></c>
      </x>
    </b>
  </x>
  <x>x
    <d class="select">select
      <x>x
        <c>c
          <d>d
            <x>x
              <d>d</d>
            </x>
          </d>
        </c>
      </x>
    </d>
    </a>



